# Typscript Error on Class Constructor - No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BarberModel'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I have a class constructor and I want populate it with an object that I receive in constructor. But I don't know how to solve this TS error on line `this[key] = object[key]`

Code

```
constructor(object: any) {
        if (object) {
          for (const key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              this[key] = object[key];
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) when asking a question.

Comment: what even this `this[key] = object[key];` suppost to mean? You wanna store a class variable so your other methods could use it? If so then hwy dont you just open a documentation. First create a variable (pref above the constructor method) like `private variableName: variableType` then in constructor `this.variableName = someValue`. also dont forget that in order to access the key property like `this.variableName[key]` the `this.VariableName` HAS to be initialized first. otherwise it will error you out.

Comment: In this[key] = object[key] I am populating my class model with the data that came from the object.